# How to draw a line of x, y points in java where x and y are double type?

Tags: java, jpanel, line, draw

How can I draw a line of x, y points? I tried using Graphics 2D but I get the error "The method drawLine(int, int, int, int) in the type Graphics is not applicable for the arguments (double, double, double, double)". How can I plot the line in java if I don't use Graphics 2D?

```
public void paint(Graphics g){  
                                float []data= Series.getY();
                                double x1 = 0;
                                double y1 = 0;
                                for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                                    double x2 = i;
                                    double y2 = data[i];
                                    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
                                    y1 = y2;
                                    x1 = x2;
                                }
                                }
```

I have tried this

```
 public class PlotPanel {
     public void paint (Graphics g) {
                float []data= Series.getY();
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                double y1 = 0;
                double x1 = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                double x2 = i;
                double y2 = data[i];
                g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2));
                y1 = y2;
                x1 = x2;
                        }
                    }           
public static void main(String args[]) {    
    PlotPanel pp = new PlotPanel();
    pp.paint(g2);
    }
```

}

It says g2 cannot be resolved to a variable. How can I check if it works?

Comment: kindly edit your post to show what programming language you use in the tags.

Answer (score 1):

The prototype of drawLine is drawLine(int, int, int, int) and you give to drawLine 4 variable of type double. You can test to swap all of double in int.

Hope help you.

Comment: I have edited my code. Please see if you can help me further on it..the error I get here is "g2 cannot be resolved to a variable" in the main method.